# Problems succesfully installing and configure wordpress on Debian 7

Tags: wordpress, apache2, debian

I am following the next guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5PyL8Nb_ic and this one too https://wiki.debian.org/WordPress.

Well my problem is simple I guess the install works but when I try to make the fully configurations of wordpress on my local machine using localhost or 127.0.0.1.

Wordpress page is not showing out the page that I see is the **"It works!!!"** form apache I guess so I can't been able to finish the proper installation of wordpress.

So that is the main problem. And why I am trying to do is to run this machine as a server for wordpress. thank you very much for any help and comments if you need more information about my problem I will post that.

*I am installing in a physical machine and in a virtual machine two and same problem on both options.*

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't link your wordpress folder in your apache conf file or your wordpress dir isn't at the right place.

Did you place your wordpress folder in /var/www/html/ ?

You can do it with

```
sudo rsync -avP ~/wordpress/ /var/www/html/
```

You have also to check the files permissions (need to be readable from everyone)

You can also try to check your apache conf file to see where it links.

Comment: well first of all thank you very much for your help but. I cant use rsync bash can't find the order. another important thing is that I dont have the html folder. And another important point is that when in the browser hit the localhost/wp show this error: **Neither /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php nor /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php could be found.
Ensure one of them exists, is readable by the webserver and contains the right password/username.**